# Keycloak SSO change user

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, idp

I have set up Keycloak using Microsoft and Google SSO.

The system, allows users that already have an account in key cloak to login, else they are rejected.

The login flow asks for the username first, and then evaluate if the user should use SSO, based on that.

The issue is, when a users is logged in with a different user account than expected.

Example:
User is logged in with john@doe.com in the bowser for one Microsoft account, but would like to access my system using doe@john.com

Then when trying to login, the users is simply rejected, with an error that it was not possible to login using john@doe.com

The only way to get the user logged in, is that the user goes back to either google og MS, logs out from doe@john.com.

I would like to be able to redirect the user back to the IDP (ms/google) to be able to choose a diffrent account.

Comment: i cann't understand your example. You have a keycloak server and config two idp (may be ms/google, and these idp providers have email as theire identity), then how are you archieve `logged in with john@doe.com in the bowser for one Microsoft account, but would like to access my system using doe@john.com`. Could you provide more detail about the opration or post some picture to show how to reproduce this case.